# Trouble executing a unit test that should ignore Spring annotations on the unit under test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, asynchronous, junit

I'm trying to execute a unit test for a service class that has an `@Async("asyncExecutor")` annotated method. This is a plain JUnit test class with no Spring runners and no intention of using Spring at all in the unit test. I get the exception,

```
BeanFactory must be set on AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect to access qualified executor 'asyncExecutor'
```

Where `asyncExectuor` is the name of the bean to be used during normal execution. My configuration class looks like this and I solved that previous error message at runtime by adding the `mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ` portion. This service works at runtime without issue in an Async way.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class AsyncConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the Spring context is being constructed at all in the unit test. The test class is simply annotated `@Test` on the methods with no class annotations and no mention of Spring. I was hoping to unit test this service class method as a regular method ignoring the async nature, but the annotation is being processed for some reason.

I'm contributing to a much larger gradle + Spring 4 project that I'm not fully knowledgeable about. Is there anything I should be looking for to see if a Spring context is being created by default for all tests?

Comment: That exception tells you that Spring is being used. Please add the test you mentioned instead of describing it. Also apparently you are using some AOP mechanism and I suspect that is switched to AspectJ mode (using compile or load-time weaving). And please add the full stracktrace instead of a snippet of the message you get.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, Spring context is not loaded, that is the reason of your error. Try to initialize Spring context in your test by adding @RunWith and @ContextConfiguration annotations

Comment: I specifically don't want to use Spring in my unit tests, though. I'm using the Async aspect for runtime behavior, which is wholly unrelated to the business logic in my service method. I am okay with using Spring for an integration test, but it just doesn't belong here for units.

Comment: I'm using this as a workaround. I'm now using the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and `@ContextConfiguration` with a specific application context for this test. Thanks for the feedback, but my original question is still unanswered so I can't accept this one.